# Get image path and show in TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

In my MVC web app, I want to get image path from  and show it in textarea. Here is my code snippet but it did not work!

```
     <label>Load Picture</label>&ensp;
            <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" class="form-control" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function PreviewImage() {
                    var oFReader = new FileReader();
                    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

                    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                    };
                };
            </script>
            <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 350px; height: 400px;" class="form-control" /><br />

            <label>Save</label>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" onclick="LoadCuepoint();" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function LoadCuepoint() {
                  textArea1.value = path.getElementById("uploadImage");
                };
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete but I assume you already have a file input and a text area respectively. If so, following should work:

```
<input type="file" onchange="handleFilePath(this);" />
<textarea id="filePathTextArea"></textarea>
```

Once the file has changed, you should be able to read its path using a FileReader:

```
function handleFilePath(input) {
    // Initialize file variable
    var file;

    // Check if a file is actually selected
    if (input.files && (file = input.files[0])) {
        // Create a FileReader
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        // Listen to its onload event
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            // Set the result to textarea
            document.getElementById("filePathTextArea").value = e.target.result;
        };

        // Then read the file
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```